# Как выставить, чтобы TextView был под ImageView?

Tags: android, java

Получается просто так, что текст налазит на картинку, а как мне сделать, так чтобы он был под ней?

```
 <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="55"    android:layout_weight="0.2">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/homeButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_home_g"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_button2"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    />
            <TextView  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBottom="@id/homeButton" android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_home"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Пробывал разные `scaleType`, не помогает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно сделать как посоветовал Виталий - это в данном контексте самый верный способ.

А можно реализовать через `TableLayout` посадить `ImageView` и `TextView` на разные `TableRow`

IMHO `RelativeLayout` тяжелое орудие, когда надо кнопку прижать книзу или там справа/слева от чего то. А здесь лэйаут довольно простой и посему `TableLayout` будет в точку.

Comment: Почему RelativeLayout - это тяжелое орудие? Google вроде как рекомендует использовать везде, где можно этот тип лэйаута. Для такой простой задачи, о которой был вопрос он подходит лучше всего. TableLayout в таких простых случаях лучше не использовать. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Не знаю где и почему это рекомендуется его везде использовать - не слышал. RelativeLayout действительно мощное средство и оно рекомендовано для использования там где есть многоуровневые вложенности вьюшек. Здесь все довольно просто и не вижу причин почему бы не использовать TableLayout - самое оно. Впрочем на вкус и цвет - как известно...

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так

```
android:layout_below="@id/homeButton"
```

Answer (score 0):

Поместите 2 вью в один контейнер LinearLayout и укажите для него вертикальную ориентацию

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="55"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/bg_button2"
            android:id="@+id/homeButton"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home_g" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_home" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="0.15">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/homeButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_home_g"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_button2"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/homeButtonText" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="0.05">
            <TextView
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_gravity="center"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      style="@style/buttonFont"
                      android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_home"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```